# nvim-lspconfig cannot go to definition to jdk or external library

Tags: neovim, lsp, kickstart

I'm using Kickstart.nvim config with enabled jdtls LSP server for java but I have problem with go to function definition.

`vim.lsp.buf.definition()` command (to jump to the definition) works for all the project files (maven project) but not for any of standard java libraries or external libraries (downloaded from maven using gradle).

Completion and diagnostics are working perfectly fine with standard and external libraries but not go to definition.